# Does Spider-Man have a brother?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

When I was a child, I read a Spider-Man comic where Spider-Man was not Peter Parker, but rather a guy with a beard and a costume that left his arms bare except for the wristbands and his web-slingers. Somewhere in that comic, as far as I remember, he mentioned that he is the brother of Peter. Can anyone give me more information about that? Or was it just a dream of mine? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It could be Ben Reilly. He had wrist bands for the web shooters, he was Peter Parker's clone who was presented as his cousin (which you could have interpreted as brother) and during the clone saga he often had an untidy appearance

[image].

There was also Kaine, another clone but I don't recall him being Spider-man.

[image]

Comment: THATS IT! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Wait, I thought Ben was the real Peter, and the one who had lived as Peter was the clone?  Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @Jeff That's what Norman Osborn wanted you to think... That was true for awhile, from about Amazing 407-418 when Norman was unmasked as the "genius" behind the whole clone saga and Peter = real and Ben = Clone was put back as the status quo.